# Snowflake ON_ERROR=CONTINUE abort the COPY command for file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-pipe

Snowkflake documentation for `COPY INTO` command states (for COPY options)

> ON_ERROR = CONTINUE | SKIP_FILE | SKIP_FILE_num | SKIP_FILE_num% | ABORT_STATEMENT

> Continue loading the file. The COPY statement returns an error message
> for a maximum of one error encountered per data file. Note that the
> difference between the ROWS_PARSED and ROWS_LOADED column values
> represents the number of rows that include detected errors. However,
> each of these rows could include multiple errors. To view all errors
> in the data files, use the VALIDATION_MODE parameter or query the
> VALIDATE function.

But for me, it just doesn't seem to obey, as I see the default value i.e SKIP_FILE is getting applied as files are getting skipped on any error in the file.

```
create or replace file format jsonThing type = 'json' DATE_FORMAT='yyyy-mm-dd' 
   TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSZ' TRIM_SPACE=TRUE NULL_IF=('\\N', 'NULL',''); 

create or replace stage snowflake_json_stage
   storage_integration = snowflake_json_storage_integration
   url = 'azure://snowflakejson.blob.core.windows.net/cdrs'
   file_format = jsonThing
   COPY_OPTIONS = (ON_ERROR=CONTINUE PURGE=TRUE MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME=CASE_INSENSITIVE)
   COMMENT='The snowflake json stage';

CREATE or REPLACE PIPE SNOWFLAKE_JSON_PIPE
   AUTO_INGEST = TRUE
   integration = snowflake_json_notification_integration
   as
   COPY INTO purge.public.cdrs
   from @SNOWFLAKE_JSON_STAGE 
   ON_ERROR=CONTINUE 
   MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME=CASE_INSENSITIVE;
```

Do `ON_ERROR=CONTINUE` options work with PIPE?

NOTE: The file is an NDJSON file.

Comment: Where are you seeing `SKIP_FILE` being applied?  Is it possible that the whole file is bad and you are just seeing the first issue?

Comment: No, I cross-check after I remove the bad JSON and reupload the file to Azure the alone JSON (valid) get inserted. Also does not work if change the order of BAD and Valid json in the file.

Comment: ON_ERROR=CONTINUE will ignore bad file and attempt to load remaining files, At end it will display the status of each file, Are you referring same here?

Comment: @Sriga What I meant was if a file is a NDJSON file. I'm expecting the PIPE to work and insert all the GOOD/VALID JSON and not stop or abort the loading of that file if it encounters a BAD/INVALID JSON. Much like how this guy has explained it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156843/how-to-parse-json-efficiently-in-snowpipe-with-on-error-continue?rq=1 just that it does not work for me. Else to the CONITINUE Options does not make sense based on what you are referring since it essentially is `SKIP_FILE` then?

Comment: @sriga `CONTINUE` will continue to load records from the file.  `SKIP_FILE` will skip the file and move to the next one.

Comment: Your questions is about whether ON_ERROR works with PIPEs, but I can't see in your question if you tested this with a straight COPY command or not. Can you try it and let us know the result?

Comment: @Hotchips does that matter because if it does doc should  be more clear that `ON_ERROR=CONTINUE` is not supported for pipe

Comment: @Hotchips also check without PIPE does not work.

Comment: Thanks @Noobie. I suspect this is in the interaction of MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME and ON_ERROR - I think your best option is to contact Snowflake Support to see what they can tell you about it.